# Long time between HttpRequest and LastHttpContent

Tags: http, netty

I'm new to netty and I'm trying to build a HTTP server  that listens for incoming data from a single client. The HTTP request are about 200Kb and we get about 10/sec.

My problem is that the latency to respond to these requests is very high (almost 8 seconds) and some requests timeout completely and my AWS load balancer is showing 5XX responses.

Here's my setup below, and ideas why the latencies might be so high. From looking at the wireshark trace I can see that the TCP segments of the request are quite far apart.

**Server**

```
public void run() {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)
                            throws Exception {

                        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                        p.addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
                        p.addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
                        p.addLast(new FacebookHttpServerHandler());
                    }

                }).option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, 100)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024);

        // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();

        log.info("before shutdown server...");

        // Wait until the server socket is closed.
        // shut down your server.
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("unexpected exception", e);
    }

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            log.info("shutdown gracefully...");
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String host = "localhost";
    int port;
    if (args.length > 0) {
        host = args[0];
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    } else {
        port = 8080;
    }

    log.info("host :" + host + " ,  port : " + port);
    new FacebookCollector(host, port).run();
}
```

**Handler**

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        HttpRequest request = this.request = (HttpRequest) msg;

        if (HttpUtil.is100ContinueExpected(request)) {
            send100Continue(ctx);
        }
    }

    if (msg instanceof HttpContent) {
        HttpContent httpContent = (HttpContent) msg;

        ByteBuf content = httpContent.content();
        if (content.isReadable()) {
            buf.append(content.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
            // TODO appendDecoderResult(buf, request);
        }

        if (msg instanceof LastHttpContent) {
            LastHttpContent trailer = (LastHttpContent) msg;

            processFeed(buf.toString());

            if (!writeResponse(trailer, ctx)) {
                // If keep-alive is off, close the connection once the
                // content is fully written.
                ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(
                        ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: You could turning `TCP_NODELAY` to false as it allows the network stack to combine multiple responses. But we need to see more code before we can solve the problem

Comment: What other code would be helpful?